# Looking for Open Source Math Software with Poor Documentation

Tags: big-list, math-software

I'm a techie who is looking to transition to technical writing as a career. It's been suggested that I produce documentation for an Open Source project to demonstrate my ability to do technical writing. I love Math so I thought I'd find a gap in an Open Source Math program and fill that gap.

What poorly documented Open Source Math software can you recommend that I look at?

Comment: I know this probably isn't what you are looking for, but I have been playing around a ton with Blender for 3-d modeling (so it's partially mathematical), and it's a really cool program with not a terrible amount of documentation, from what I could tell.  [www.blender.org](http://www.blender.org/)

Comment: I upvoted for your charity intentions solely. Felt right.

Answer (score 14):

Consider [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), the open-source version of the computer algebra system Macsyma (similar to Mathematica and Maple). If you post a similar question to their [mailing list](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/maximalist.html) then I suspect that some folks would quickly point you at various parts of the system with little or weak documentation. Since Maxima is a general-purpose system you are more likely to find some area that intersects your interests and expertise.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I've joined their mailing list and sent my question there.

Answer (score 11):

R software actually has good documentation in many areas, but it is becoming quite vast with many add-on packages which are not part of the base. I would target a few contributed packages which have bad documentation and offer to improve. Cannot suggest any particulars but refer to all of the contributed packages at: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/

Comment: Nice suggestion. Thank you. I'd give you a vote up but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation points to do that.

Answer (score 10):

I imagine there's room for improvement in the documentation of *any* open source math project. So instead of looking for a project that's poorly documented, you might look for a project that interests you and then see how you can help.

Most open source documentation is fairly low-level, one step above reading code comments. Often what's missing is high-level introductions or case studies.  When a projects as a good "quick start" guide, it is much appreciated.  Maybe you could find a project in need of a quick start guide.

Answer (score 5):

If it is also allowed that the software itself is poorly written ;-) then you might be interested in my matrix-calculator MatMate. Here we have much less functionality to describe than in Maxima et al. - just a simple, but nontrivial matrix "pocket" calculator.

Because there are many errors you have even the possibility to include criticism concerning technology/ implementation and concerning the syntax/ semantic-paradigms (which may be interesting for someone who is beginning a writer's carreer). http://go.helms-net.de/sw/matmate/index.htm The exisiting documentation is in german language but possibly gives an idea how to approach a not-too-big introduction/documentation.

(well, even if this all sounds a bit funny/sarcastic when I reread my own msg - that was not intended but -perhaps- unavoidable. Instead maybe such a tiny software is indeed a better start than a full-featured one)

Answer (score 4):

While not purely a mathematics package, **OpenSSL** is probably the most widely-used software I've ever seen whose documentation is just awful.  It's often wrong, very confusing, and after 12 years still says "[STILL INCOMPLETE]" on every section of the [documentation.](http://www.openssl.org/docs/)

Comment: OpenSSL is in no way a mathematics package.

Comment: @Mitch: OpenSSL does have an arbitrary precision arithmetic subsystem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this project http://www.formulae.org It is open source, it is about math and it is partially documented.

There are several sources for documentation: the developer's guide (LaTeX, partially), the front-end user´s guide (LaTeX, starting), the API reference (JavaDoc, partially) and expression dictionary (online wiki, partially)

Answer (score 2):

Great question! I would like to suggest you to have a look to some Python libraries specialized on Mathematics, like [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) or [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/).

I use them often to study and make my tests, and I miss always some extra explanations or samples in the online documentation. They are really great, and some extra samples and theory-related explanations would be imho a good add-on for them. Good luck in your search!